# Trying to dynamically edit a url based on form validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, validation

so I'm new to JS, but basically I have a form, where I collect user's Twitter usernames and from that I would like to dynamically create a link to the user's twitter account (https://twitter.com/INPUT_USERNAME). So far I have

```
  const {handleSubmit, handleTwitterChange, values, errors, isSubmitting, setValues} = formValidation(initialState, inputErrors, axiosFunc);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="link-error-msg">
        <p id="added">{added ? 'Twitter Added To Your Profile!' : ''}</p>
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="newlink-buttons">
          <input type="text" name="username" value={values.username} onChange={handleTwitterChange} placeholder={'Twitter Username'}/>
          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting} className="user-submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

Additionally, I have the below, but I'm not sure what to actually put inside the handleTwitterChange so that it adds the username from the form to https://twitter.com/ because it's dealing with urls. Thanks!

```
  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const validationErrors = validate(values);
    setErrors(validationErrors);
    setSubmitting(true);
  }

  function handleTwitterChange(event) {

  }

  return {
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    values,
    errors,
    isSubmitting, 
    setValues
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are maintaining a state for the username change

```
function handleTwitterChange(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   let twitterURL = "https://twitter.com/"
   twitterURL=  twitterURL + values.username
  }
```

I don't know how you are maintaining the twitter URL so I just create a local variable